# Scala Strategy Pattern Design Problems

Tags: scala, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

Inspired by my C# implementation of generic Strategy pattern I want to do the same in Scala. I want also make some functional programming to encapsulate Strategy algorithms inside a inherited class.
So what I've done yet is:

```
trait Strategy {
  type T <: Strategy
  type O

  def Call(victim: T): O = {
    strategy(victim)
  }
  var strategy: (this.T => this.O)
}
```

This is a trait which is a base of scaldfolding. I have also a `StrategyFactory` class:

```
case class StrategyFactory[T <: Strategy, O](str: T) {
  def Call(x: (T => O)) = x(str)
}

object StrategyFactory {

}
```

And finally in my code I can create concrete Strategy:

```
 class DownloadStrategy(path: String) extends Strategy {
  type T = DownloadStrategy
  type O = String
 strategy = (dw: DownloadStrategy) => path + "aaaa"
}

object DownloadStrategy {
  def apply(s: String) = new DownloadStrategy(s)
}
```

In my application code I have this:

```
var ds = DownloadStrategy("j")
val m = StrategyFactory[DownloadStrategy, String](ds)
var output = m.Call(ds.strategy)
```

**Here works everything good.**

*I want to have functional strategies thus there is `m.Call(ds.strategy)`*

But It is very dummy design because I cannot create a set of classes which will be extending `DownloadStrategy`. For example:

```
class ImageDownloadStrategy(w: String, h: String, path: String) extends DownloadStrategy(path){
  type T = ImageDownloadStrategy
  type O = String
  strategy = (ids: T) => path + ":ImageDownloadStrategy"
}

class VideoDownloadStrategy(w: String, h: String, path: String) extends DownloadStrategy(path){
  type T = VideoDownloadStrategy
  type O = String
  strategy = (ids: T) => path + ":VideoDownloadStrategy"
}
```

And so on. Basically I want to have one base class of some default strategy and subclasses are more specific implementations.

This brings me to application code where I would like to code something like this:

```
var ds: DownloadStrategy = null
request.getQueryString("t") match {
   case "1" => ds = ImageDownloadStrategy("","","")
   case "2" => ds = VideoDownloadStrategy("","","")
   case "3" => ds = RawFileDownloadStrategy("","","")
   case _ => ds = DownloadStrategy("")
}

var output = (StrategyFactory[DownloadStrategy, String](ds)).Call(ds.strategy)
```

I thought that when I write `StrategyFactory[DownloadStrategy, String](ds)` the compiler will be so smart enought that can figure if `ImageDownloadStrategy` is subclass of `DownloadStrategy` will could allow me to do some polimorphic calls but i cannot do it.

Another fact is that I need to overrides `type T` and `type O` in delivered class from `DownloadStrategy` but I dont have any idea how to do it.

Please give me some advices how to model this kind of behaviour.

**EDIT(for pagoda_5b details)**

As I have mentioned I have functional `var strategy` in `trait Strategy` which is `var strategy: (this.T => this.O)`. This variable need to be overriden in classes implementing this trait. Also I have 2 generic types which `T` means subclass of concrete strategy and `O` indicate result type from `def Call(...)`.

What I want to achive is having functional strategies inside subclass of Strategy and then make polimorphic calls. Here I have got `DownloadStrategy` which is default strategy and I have some subclasses with specicif algorithms. I want cast `ImageDownloadStrategy` to `DownloadStrategy` and use it as I showed in switch case statement.

Comment: All this work can be easily replaced by using functions as values, which is one of the great benefits of functional programming, and thus of scala. I can't write a complete answer if you don't give some more detail on how the single strategies should use their construction arguments (i.e. w, h, path)

Comment: Is the fact that the `strategy` member is mutable important? If so I don't like this pattern from a functional perspecitve. If not, it's just a function `T => O`, no?

Comment: @ziggystar I don't know what mean mutable? It means changeable? I would agree that strategy could be a val but need to be overriden or implemented in sublcasses.

Comment: mutable here means using a `var` instead of a `val` which makes the `Strategy` trait mutable. Your subclasses can still override the `val`. The difference between the two is that immutable values cannot be reassigned, somewhat like `final` or `constant`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I'll try to take a shot.

Since you can have function objects, you probably can simply do without any of the machinery of a `Strategy` hierarchy or factory whatsoever.

You can for example

```
//this is sort of a factory
object Strategies {

  //a type alias to better define your selected functions
  type Strategy[T, O] = T => O

  //a set of methods to obtain the correct strategy "on demand"
  def imageDownload[T](w: String, h: String, path: String): Strategy[T, String] = 
    (t: T) =>
      path + ":ImageDownloadStrategy"


  def videoDownload[T](w: String, h: String, path: String): Strategy[T, String] =
    (t: T) =>
      path + ":VideoDownloadStrategy"

  def rawFileDownload[T](w: String, h: String, path: String): Strategy[T, String] =
    (t: T) =>
      path + ":RawDownloadStrategy"

  //this is the fallback default
  def download[T](path: String): Strategy[T, String] =
    (t: T) =>
      path + "aaaa"

}

object Client {
  //make the strategies visible
  import Strategies._

  //processes the request
  def process(request: Request): String = {
    //here val means that the strategy variable won't be reassigned, ever
    val strategy = selectStrategy[T](request.getQueryString("t")) //here we miss the type of the input value
    //this assignment could be omitted if it's just returned
    val output = strategy(??) //Here I'm missing the input to the strategy
    output
  }

  //a method to select the strategy to use
  def selectStrategy[T](selector: String): Strategy[T, String] = 
    selector match {
      case "1" => imageDownload("","","")
      case "2" => videoDownload("","","")
      case "3" => rawFileDownload("","","")
      case _ => download("")
    }

}
```

As you can see, I'm missing what is the input value passed from the request to the strategy, so there are a couple holes in the `process` method

I don't know if this is what you need, but it could give you an idea why the strategy pattern is not so useful in functional languages, but rather needlessly cumbersome.

**EDIT**

Finally I found time to post real life example of downloading strategy in playframework.

```
object Download{
  object Type extends Enumeration {
    type Type = Value
    val Image = "1"
    val Video = "2"
    val Pdf = "3"
    val File = "4"
  }
}

object Strategies {
  type Strategy[T, O] = T => O

def imageDownload[T](): Strategy[T, java.io.File] =
    (t: T) => {
      //Receive download strategy information
      val dw = t.asInstanceOf[DownloadStrategy]
      //juicy code goes here
      java.io.File.createTempFile("", "")
    }

  def videoDownload[T](): Strategy[T, java.io.File] =
    (t: T) =>
      java.io.File.createTempFile("", "")

  def rawFileDownload[T](): Strategy[T, java.io.File] =
    (t: T) =>
      java.io.File.createTempFile("", "")

  //this is the fallback default
  def download[T](): Strategy[T, java.io.File] =
    (t: T) => {
      java.io.File.createTempFile("", "")
    }

  //a method to select the strategy to use
  def selectStrategy[T](selector: String): Strategy[T, java.io.File] =
    selector match {
      case Download.Type.Image => {
        imageDownload()
      }
      case Download.Type.Video => {
        videoDownload()
      }
      case Download.Type.Pdf => {
        rawFileDownload()
      }
      case Download.Type.File => {
        rawFileDownload()
      }
      case _ => download()
    }
}

case class DownloadStrategy(request: Request[AnyContent], path: String, file: Option[File]) {

}

//Controller code
def download(path: String) = Action {
    implicit request =>
      val file: Option[File] = FileStore.byPath(path, true)
      val ds = DownloadStrategy(request, path, file)
      //request.getQueryString("t") - Download type
      val str = Strategies.selectStrategy[DownloadStrategy](request.getQueryString("t").getOrElse(""))
      val x = str(ds)
      Ok.sendFile(
        content = x
      )
  }
```